# How does one transition from using a list of functions to using classes in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, python-2.7, oop

Let me start off by stating that I am completely self-taught in programming with python throught trial and error and a lot of googling, so please excuse my ignorance of propper programming terminology.

That being said, lets pretend I'm writing code that scrapes a website and returns a few pieces of information. In the very early stages of testing I would have the code writen "line-by-line", as in, outside of any function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping"
headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
print soup.title
```

Then as the script gets validated and more complex I might put larger "single task actions" of code into functions:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def make_soup(url):
    headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
    return soup

def list_table_of_contents(soup):
    toc_elem = soup.find('div', id = 'toc')
    toc_level1 = toc_elem.find_all('li', class_ = 'toclevel-1')
    toc_level1_list = [i.text for i in toc_level1]
    return toc_level1_list

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping"
soup = make_soup(url)
toc_level1_list = list_table_of_contents(soup)
for i in toc_level1_list:
    print i
```

The problem is once it gets to the point where I have 10 different functions in one script it becomes really hard to comprehend whats going on and do revisions. I'm guessing that using classes would be the next logical step, but I'm not sure how I would implement them in something like what I described above...

In my mind "line-by-line" programming is like writing a recipe, and using functions is like making factories that follow specific recipes (input -> output), so then what are classes?

From what I've read about classes and learned from playing with them, they are essentially a way to easily create multiple "objects" with specific attributes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I usually use classes in python when the default data structures aren't enough. I...honestly don't really see the connection between many functions -> classes. Many functions -> breaking up this file into smaller files, maybe.

Comment: That said: Any excuse to start OOP is a good excuse to start OOP. It's amazingly powerful if used correctly.

Comment: Suggest you start by reading the Wikipedia article on [Classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29) and then ask more specific questions if needed.

Comment: You should google "Python object-oriented tutorial", or similar. OOP is a life-long learning pursuit; every day I learn about or sometimes even invent a new way to make my code more readable and more better.

Answer (score 2):

an example class based implementation of the above. Hopefully it makes sense. Classes can make things easier as it allows you to abstract functionality and then inherit from one class or another. In the class below, we are inheriting from the base `object` class.

```
class MyBeautifulScraper(object):

    def __init__(self, site_to_scrape, headers={'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}):
        self.site_to_scrape = site_to_scrape
        self.headers = headers
        self.soup = None

    def make_soup(self):
        page = requests.get(self.site_to_scrap, headers = self.headers)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)

    def get_title(self):
        return self.soup.title

    def list_table_of_contents(self):
        toc_elem = self.soup.find('div', id = 'toc')
        toc_level1 = toc_elem.find_all('li', class_ = 'toclevel-1')
        toc_level1_list = [i.text for i in toc_level1]
        return toc_level1_list

my_soup = MyBeautifulScraper("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
print my_soup.get_title()
toc_level1_list = my_soup.list_table_of_contents()

for i in toc_level1_list:
    print i
```

You could add functionality to the class without recreating it and simply by creating a specialized class that inherits from the above and then extending it with additional functionality:

```
class AnotherScraper(MyBeautifulScraper):

    def additional_functionality(self):
        ....

    # override existing functionality and make it do something different
    def get_title(self):
        return 'Title: {0}'.format(self.soup.title)
```

This is what makes Object Oriented Programming so powerful. The fact that you can re-use and extend pre-existing classes to inherit or override existing functionality without losing the initial functionality.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not entirely sure what you're doing but I can possibly give some intuition on what classes are used for. For this example let's say we're making a video game since that is probably the most straight forward example. In my video game I want to have players, and these players all fit the general mold of what you would imagine a player to be but they exhibit different behavior. Let look at this example.

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name_arg, ability_arg):
        self.name = name_arg
        self.ability = ability_arg
```

In this example you would create a player like this `my_player = Player('smbullet', 'python_programming')`. And if I wanted to do something with those attributes I can then create functions that use them:

```
class Player():
    # ...
    def attack(self, enemy):
        # prints "smbullet used python_programming to attack enemy_name
        print "%s used %s to attack %s" % self.name, self.ability, enemy
```

And that will be called by `my_player.attack(my_enemy)`

The moral of the story I guess is if you are doing something exactly the same all the time, then a bunch of different functions isn't a terrible idea. However, if all of these procedures need to vary in different ways then you might want to look into using classes.

Comment: You should look at @Incognos answer btw. Much better than mine

Answer (score 0):

As a very general oversimplification, classes should be used when you have
objects that have some data and behaviour associated with them.  So in your
example, let's assume you'll be dealing with pages to be scraped repeatedly
in your code.  You could then make a Page class which encapsulates behaviour
and data associated with a page.  For example, a page might have a method to
scrape itself, to give a table of contents as you did, etc.  It also has data
associated with it: its URL, scraped text, etc.  Whatever makes sense for the
task at hand.  As you gain experience, you'll become better at figuring out
what exactly is it that makes sense in a particular situation.

So in your case, the page class might look like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

class Page(object):
    # If all the pages use the same headers during scraping, you can have
    # a class attribute.  If they do not share headers then move it into
    # __init__, similar to url and name.
    headers = {"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

    def __init__(self, url, name):
        self.url = url
        self.name = name

    def soup(self):
        page = requests.get(self.url, self.headers)

        return BeautifulSoup(page.text)

    # And so on...
```

If not all your pages have a table of contents, then you might make a subclass
of pages which do have it.  You simply subclass the Page and add the
functionality:

```
 class PageWithTableOfContents(Page):

     def list_table_of_contents(self):
         souped = self.soup()
         toc_elem = souped.find("div", id="toc")
         toc_level1 = toc_elem.find_all("li", class_="toclevel-1")

         return [i.text for i in toc_level1]
```

Or, you can go the way Incognos [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31251710/3188213) and base your classes around the scraper.
Whatever fits your bill better.

I think it should be pointed out that it's easy to get carried away a lot of
times, so you end up with complicated taxonomies, and inefficient code that is
hard to maintain.  In [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)
you can see where piling classes without reason or rhyme can lead.

In Python, since everything is an object, and functions are
[first class objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)
*sometimes* the pythonic way is to do things using functions instead of classes.
[This talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/146/pycon-2009--the--lack-of--design-patterns-in-pyth)
illustrates some interesting, more pythonic ways of doing stuff in Python which would require more complicated class setups in other languages. It's not directly related to your question but it might give you a feel of how things should be done in Python.  [Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)
is also a good read if you haven't read it already.